# Parse ping log to find total downtime

Tags: python, python-2.x, parsing

Trying to write a utility script to get downtime measurements from ping logs which generally look like this:

```
Mar 25 00:07:13 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2499 ttl=64 time=0.320 ms
Mar 25 00:07:14 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2500 ttl=64 time=0.324 ms
Mar 25 00:07:15 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2501 ttl=64 time=0.368 ms
Mar 25 00:07:16 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2502 ttl=64 time=0.310 ms
Mar 25 00:07:17 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2503 ttl=64 time=0.351 ms
Mar 25 00:07:18 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2504 ttl=64 time=0.299 ms
Mar 25 00:07:19 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2505 ttl=64 time=0.341 ms
Mar 25 00:07:20 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2506 ttl=64 time=0.290 ms
Mar 25 00:07:21 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2507 ttl=64 time=0.363 ms
Mar 25 00:07:22 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2508 ttl=64 time=0.299 ms
Mar 25 00:07:23 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2509 ttl=64 time=0.336 ms
Mar 25 00:07:24 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2510 ttl=64 time=0.285 ms
Mar 25 00:07:25 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2511 ttl=64 time=0.350 ms
Mar 25 00:07:26 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2512 ttl=64 time=0.319 ms
Mar 25 00:07:27 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2513 ttl=64 time=0.377 ms
Mar 25 00:07:28 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2514 ttl=64 time=0.260 ms
Mar 25 00:08:07 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2550 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:07 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2551 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:07 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2552 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:10 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2553 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:10 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2554 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:10 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2555 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:13 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2556 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:13 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2557 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:13 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2558 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:16 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2559 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:16 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2560 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:16 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2561 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:19 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2562 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:19 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2563 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:19 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2564 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:22 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2565 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:22 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2566 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:22 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2567 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:25 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2568 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:25 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2569 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:25 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2570 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:29 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2571 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:29 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2572 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:29 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2573 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:32 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2574 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:32 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2575 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:32 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2576 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:35 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2577 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:38 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2581 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:38 From 10.11.10.1 icmp_seq=2582 Destination Host Unreachable
Mar 25 00:08:39 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2583 ttl=64 time=1001 ms
Mar 25 00:08:39 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2584 ttl=64 time=1.34 ms
Mar 25 00:08:40 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2585 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms
Mar 25 00:08:41 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2586 ttl=64 time=0.256 ms
Mar 25 00:08:42 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2587 ttl=64 time=0.263 ms
Mar 25 00:08:43 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2588 ttl=64 time=0.302 ms
Mar 25 00:08:44 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2589 ttl=64 time=0.394 ms
Mar 25 00:08:45 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2590 ttl=64 time=0.355 ms
Mar 25 00:08:46 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2591 ttl=64 time=0.293 ms
Mar 25 00:08:47 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2592 ttl=64 time=0.384 ms
Mar 25 00:08:48 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2593 ttl=64 time=0.319 ms
Mar 25 00:08:49 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2594 ttl=64 time=0.228 ms
Mar 25 00:08:50 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2595 ttl=64 time=0.316 ms
Mar 25 00:08:51 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2596 ttl=64 time=0.281 ms
Mar 25 00:08:52 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2597 ttl=64 time=0.301 ms
Mar 25 00:08:53 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2598 ttl=64 time=0.283 ms
Mar 25 00:08:54 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2599 ttl=64 time=0.232 ms
Mar 25 00:08:55 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2600 ttl=64 time=0.349 ms
Mar 25 00:08:56 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2601 ttl=64 time=0.259 ms
Mar 25 00:08:57 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2602 ttl=64 time=0.297 ms
Mar 25 00:08:58 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2603 ttl=64 time=0.257 ms
Mar 25 00:08:59 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2604 ttl=64 time=0.242 ms
Mar 25 00:09:00 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2605 ttl=64 time=0.332 ms
Mar 25 00:09:01 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2606 ttl=64 time=0.369 ms
Mar 25 00:09:02 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2607 ttl=64 time=0.276 ms
Mar 25 00:09:03 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2608 ttl=64 time=0.370 ms
Mar 25 00:09:04 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2609 ttl=64 time=0.301 ms
Mar 25 00:09:05 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2610 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
Mar 25 00:09:06 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2611 ttl=64 time=0.313 ms
Mar 25 00:09:07 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2612 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
```

but sometimes they don't contain the unreachability lines:

```
Mar 24 23:58:31 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1977 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms
Mar 24 23:58:32 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1978 ttl=64 time=0.282 ms
Mar 24 23:58:33 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1979 ttl=64 time=0.269 ms
Mar 24 23:58:34 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1980 ttl=64 time=0.342 ms
Mar 24 23:58:35 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1981 ttl=64 time=0.261 ms
Mar 24 23:58:36 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1982 ttl=64 time=0.292 ms
Mar 24 23:58:37 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1983 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms
Mar 24 23:58:38 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1984 ttl=64 time=0.394 ms
Mar 24 23:58:39 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1985 ttl=64 time=0.338 ms
Mar 24 23:58:40 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1986 ttl=64 time=0.304 ms
Mar 24 23:58:41 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1987 ttl=64 time=0.338 ms
Mar 24 23:58:42 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1988 ttl=64 time=0.302 ms
Mar 24 23:58:43 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1989 ttl=64 time=0.302 ms
Mar 24 23:58:44 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1990 ttl=64 time=0.328 ms
Mar 24 23:58:45 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1991 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms
Mar 24 23:59:24 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2030 ttl=64 time=1.00 ms
Mar 24 23:59:25 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2031 ttl=64 time=0.333 ms
Mar 24 23:59:26 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2032 ttl=64 time=0.279 ms
Mar 24 23:59:27 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2033 ttl=64 time=0.272 ms
Mar 24 23:59:28 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2034 ttl=64 time=0.282 ms
Mar 24 23:59:29 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2035 ttl=64 time=0.430 ms
Mar 24 23:59:30 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2036 ttl=64 time=0.364 ms
Mar 24 23:59:31 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2037 ttl=64 time=0.381 ms
Mar 24 23:59:32 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2038 ttl=64 time=0.414 ms
Mar 24 23:59:33 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2039 ttl=64 time=0.330 ms
Mar 24 23:59:34 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2040 ttl=64 time=0.354 ms
Mar 24 23:59:35 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2041 ttl=64 time=0.301 ms
Mar 24 23:59:36 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2042 ttl=64 time=0.305 ms
Mar 24 23:59:37 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2043 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms
Mar 24 23:59:38 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2044 ttl=64 time=0.404 ms
Mar 24 23:59:39 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2045 ttl=64 time=0.377 ms
Mar 24 23:59:40 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2046 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
Mar 24 23:59:41 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2047 ttl=64 time=0.313 ms
Mar 24 23:59:42 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2048 ttl=64 time=0.336 ms
Mar 24 23:59:43 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2049 ttl=64 time=0.313 ms
Mar 24 23:59:44 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2050 ttl=64 time=0.311 ms
Mar 24 23:59:45 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2051 ttl=64 time=0.223 ms
Mar 24 23:59:46 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2052 ttl=64 time=0.226 ms
Mar 24 23:59:47 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2053 ttl=64 time=0.241 ms
Mar 24 23:59:48 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2054 ttl=64 time=0.389 ms
Mar 24 23:59:49 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2055 ttl=64 time=0.213 ms
Mar 24 23:59:50 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2056 ttl=64 time=0.233 ms
Mar 24 23:59:51 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2057 ttl=64 time=0.553 ms
Mar 24 23:59:52 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2058 ttl=64 time=0.309 ms
Mar 24 23:59:53 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2059 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
Mar 24 23:59:54 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2060 ttl=64 time=0.453 ms
Mar 24 23:59:55 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2061 ttl=64 time=0.208 ms
Mar 24 23:59:56 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2062 ttl=64 time=0.314 ms
Mar 24 23:59:57 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2063 ttl=64 time=0.267 ms
Mar 24 23:59:58 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2064 ttl=64 time=0.384 ms
Mar 24 23:59:59 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2065 ttl=64 time=0.302 ms
Mar 25 00:00:00 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2066 ttl=64 time=0.320 ms
Mar 25 00:00:01 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2067 ttl=64 time=0.292 ms
Mar 25 00:00:02 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2068 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms
Mar 25 00:00:03 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2069 ttl=64 time=0.192 ms
Mar 25 00:00:04 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2070 ttl=64 time=0.329 ms
Mar 25 00:00:05 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2071 ttl=64 time=0.210 ms
Mar 25 00:00:06 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2072 ttl=64 time=0.199 ms
Mar 25 00:00:07 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2073 ttl=64 time=0.197 ms
Mar 25 00:00:08 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2074 ttl=64 time=0.276 ms
Mar 25 00:00:09 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2075 ttl=64 time=0.189 ms
Mar 25 00:00:10 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2076 ttl=64 time=0.258 ms
Mar 25 00:00:11 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2077 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
Mar 25 00:00:12 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2078 ttl=64 time=0.238 ms
Mar 25 00:00:13 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2079 ttl=64 time=0.178 ms
Mar 25 00:00:14 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2080 ttl=64 time=0.183 ms
Mar 25 00:00:15 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2081 ttl=64 time=0.237 ms
Mar 25 00:00:16 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2082 ttl=64 time=0.370 ms
Mar 25 00:00:17 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2083 ttl=64 time=0.211 ms
Mar 25 00:00:18 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2084 ttl=64 time=0.354 ms
Mar 25 00:00:19 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2085 ttl=64 time=0.181 ms
Mar 25 00:00:20 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2086 ttl=64 time=0.306 ms
Mar 25 00:00:21 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2087 ttl=64 time=0.217 ms
Mar 25 00:00:22 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2088 ttl=64 time=0.417 ms
Mar 25 00:00:23 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2089 ttl=64 time=0.293 ms
Mar 25 00:00:24 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2090 ttl=64 time=0.313 ms
Mar 25 00:00:25 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2091 ttl=64 time=0.222 ms
Mar 25 00:00:26 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2092 ttl=64 time=0.404 ms
Mar 25 00:00:27 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2093 ttl=64 time=0.293 ms
Mar 25 00:00:28 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2094 ttl=64 time=0.396 ms
```

but there is a gap between two entries which also means the VM was unreachable:

```
Mar 24 23:58:45 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=1991 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms
Mar 24 23:59:24 64 bytes from 10.11.10.12: icmp_seq=2030 ttl=64 time=1.00 ms
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
import csv,sys
from datetime import datetime as dt

def main(logfile):
        gap=0
        down=False
        first=True
        st_et=[]
        dt_pairs=[]
        lt=-1
        with open(logfile,'r') as lf:
                for line in lf:
                        tokens=line.split()
                        t=dt.strptime(' '.join(tokens[0:3]), '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
                        if first:
                                first=False
                                st_et.append(t)
                        else:
                                diff=(t-lt).total_seconds()
                                if diff>4:
                                        gap+=diff
                                        print t,lt, gap
                        if "Destination" in line and not down:
                                #record downtime
                                down=True
                                dt_pairs.append(t)
                        if "bytes" in line and down:
                                # ping is back up
                                down=False
                                dt_pairs.append(lt)
                        lt=t

                st_et.append(lt)

#       print st_et
        print dt_pairs
        downtime=0
        for i in range(0,len(dt_pairs),2):
                downtime+=(dt_pairs[i+1]-dt_pairs[i]).total_seconds()
        print "Downtime: %d (unreachable) + %d (gap) = %d"%(downtime,gap,downtime+gap)

main(sys.argv[1])
```

It does work but I haven't put much thought into it and I arbitrarily chose 4 as the lower bound for the gap. I am wondering if there is an easier/ more efficient / more robust solution for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a useful code. I'm going to keep this bookmarked in case I need it.

---

#### Review

> ```
> import csv,sys
> ```

- You are not using `csv` get rid of that import.

> ```
> from datetime import datetime as dt
> ```

- Why are you shortening `datetime` to `dt`? Not really needed. Even if you are using vim to write code you can use autocomplete.

> ```
> st_et=[]
> ```

- This is not really used?

> ```
> print dt_pairs
> ```

- Get rid of debug prints.

Other things I noticed

- Make it runnable.
- Follow PEP8.
- You can easily make this Python 3 compatible.
- Lot of magic numbers.

---

#### After changes are applied.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Identify downtime from ping log
"""

from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from datetime import datetime

THRESHOLD_SECONDS = 4
ERROR_EXIT = -1
PING_LOG_MONTH_COL = 0
PING_LOG_BYTES_COL = 3


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: {0} log.txt".format(__file__))
        sys.exit(ERROR_EXIT)

    display_downtime(sys.argv[1])


def display_downtime(logfile):
    gap = 0
    down = False
    first = True
    unreachable_time_pairs = []
    previous_timestamp = None

    with open(logfile, "r") as logfile_handle:
        for line in logfile_handle:

            tokens = line.split()
            timestamp = datetime.strptime(
                " ".join(tokens[PING_LOG_MONTH_COL:PING_LOG_BYTES_COL]),
                "%b %d %H:%M:%S",
            )

            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                diff = (timestamp - previous_timestamp).total_seconds()
                if diff > THRESHOLD_SECONDS:
                    gap += diff

            if "Destination" in line and not down:
                down = True
                unreachable_time_pairs.append(timestamp)
            if "bytes" in line and down:
                # ping is back up, so add previous time for unreachable_time_pairs
                down = False
                unreachable_time_pairs.append(previous_timestamp)

            previous_timestamp = timestamp

    unreachable = 0
    for i in range(0, len(unreachable_time_pairs), 2):
        unreachable += (
            unreachable_time_pairs[i + 1] - unreachable_time_pairs[i]
        ).total_seconds()

    print(
        "Downtime: {0}s (unreachable) + {1}s (gap) = {2}s".format(
            unreachable, gap, unreachable + gap
        )
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
~ python3 unreachability.py logfile.txt
Downtime: 31.0s (unreachable) + 444.0s (gap) = 475.0s
~ python2 unreachability.py logfile.txt
Downtime: 31.0s (unreachable) + 444.0s (gap) = 475.0s
~ ./unreachability.py logfile.txt
Downtime: 31.0s (unreachable) + 444.0s (gap) = 475.0s
~ ./unreachability.py logfile.txt a b c
Usage: ./unreachability.py log.txt
```